# Neutronization process

Tags: nuclear-physics, hydrogen, fusion, proton-decay

How can I find the neutronization density for cold hydrogen plasma?
Does it happen within the fusion process of protons and electrons which yields neutrons and neutrino?

Comment: Electron proton collisions do not create neutrons, or at least not with any significant probability. I'd guess you're thinking of the electron capture process but this is a special case that happens in nuclei but wouldn't happen in a plasma. You could compress the plasma to neutron star densities. Is that what you are thinking of?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about compressing the plasma to a neutron star, but at what density it would start to produce neutrons to become a neutron star?

Comment: That would be at about neutron star densities i.e. at about 10¹⁷ kg/m³

Comment: but, I want to find it myself, not using known density